# Swift: Accessing dictionary in JSON with Alamofire and private variables in a Model

Tags: json, swift, alamofire

I'm pulling out my hair with a problem that I think is pretty simple. I have successfully parsed an array of data from a JSON file to populate a tableview and and a collectionview but I am stuck on attempting to get a dictionary to load into my model.

```
{
latitude: 42.8821,
longitude: -8.541,
timezone: "Europe/Madrid",
offset: 2,
currently: {
time: 1494674291,
summary: "Drizzle",
icon: "rain",
precipIntensity: 0.1803,
precipProbability: 0.35,
precipType: "rain",
temperature: 14.73,
apparentTemperature: 14.73,
dewPoint: 11.63,
humidity: 0.82,
windSpeed: 7.15,
windBearing: 204,
cloudCover: 0.67,
pressure: 1013.37,
ozone: 378.18
},
```

I am attempting to access the 'currently' dictionary to populate my currentWeather Model.

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire

class CurrentWeather {

    private var _currentTemp: Double!
    private var _date: String!
    private var _weatherType: String!
    private var _highTemp: Double!
    private var _lowTemp: Double!
    private var _weatherDesc: String!


    var currentTemp: Double {
        if _currentTemp == nil {
            _currentTemp = 0.0
        }
        return _currentTemp
    }

    var date: String {
        if _date == nil {
            _date = ""
        }
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateStyle = .long
        dateFormatter.timeStyle = .none
        let currentDate = dateFormatter.string(from: Date())
        self._date = "Today \(currentDate)"
        return _date
    }

    var weatherType: String {
        if _weatherType == nil {
            _weatherType = ""
        }
        return _weatherType
    }

    var highTemp: Double {
        if _highTemp == nil {
            _highTemp = 0.0
        }
        return _highTemp
    }

    var lowTemp: Double {
        if _lowTemp == nil {
            _lowTemp = 0.0
        }
        return _lowTemp
    }

    var weatherDesc: String {
        if _weatherDesc == nil {
            _weatherDesc = ""
        }
        return _weatherDesc
    }



    init(currentDict: Dictionary<String, AnyObject>) {
        if let temperature = currentDict["temperature"] as? Double {
            self._currentTemp = temperature
        }
        if let icon = currentDict["icon"] as? String {
            self._weatherType = icon
        }
        if let summary = currentDict["summary"] as? String {
            self._weatherDesc = summary
        }
    }

}
```

And my VC code for the Alamofire call looks like this -

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire

class CityWeatherVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var cityNameLbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var currentTempLbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var dateLbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var currentWeatherImg: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var currentWeatherType: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var dayHighTempLbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var dayLowTempLbl: UILabel!

    var currentWeather: CurrentWeather!
    var currentWeathers = [CurrentWeather]()
    var longRangeForecast: LongRangeForecast!
    var longRangeForecasts = [LongRangeForecast]()
    var hourlyForecast: HourlyForecast!
    var hourlyForecasts = [HourlyForecast]()


    private var _segueData: SegueData!
    var segueData: SegueData {
        get {
            return _segueData
        } set {
            _segueData = newValue
        }
    }



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        downloadApiData {
            self.updateCurrentWeatherUI()
        }
    }

    func downloadApiData(completed: DownloadComplete) {

        let currentWeatherUrl = URL(string: "\(darkSkyUrl)\(segueData.latitude),\(segueData.longitude)?units=si")!
        Alamofire.request(currentWeatherUrl).responseJSON { response in
            let result = response.result

            if let dict = result.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {


                if let currently = dict["currently"] as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {

                    let current = CurrentWeather(currentDict: currently)
                    print(current) // ISSUE HERE!

                }


                if let hourly = dict["hourly"] as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
                    if let data = hourly["data"] as? [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>] {

                        for obj in data {
                            let forecast = HourlyForecast(hourlyDict: obj)
                            self.hourlyForecasts.append(forecast)
                        }
                        self.collectionView.reloadData()
                    }

                }
                if let daily = dict["daily"] as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
                    if let data = daily["data"] as? [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>] {

                        for obj in data {
                            let forecast = LongRangeForecast(longWeatherDict: obj)
                            self.longRangeForecasts.append(forecast)
                        }
                        self.longRangeForecasts.remove(at: 0)
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        completed()

    }

    // tableView - long range forecast

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "longRangeForecastCell", for: indexPath) as? LongRangeForecastCell {
            let forecast = longRangeForecasts[indexPath.row]
            cell.configureCell(longRangeForecast: forecast)
            return cell

        } else {
            return LongRangeForecastCell()
        }
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return longRangeForecasts.count
    }


    // collectionView - hourly forecast

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "hourlyForecastCell", for: indexPath) as? HourlyForecastCell {

            let forecast = hourlyForecasts[indexPath.row]
            cell.configureCell(hourlyForecast: forecast)
            return cell
        } else {
            return HourlyForecastCell()
        }

    }

    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return hourlyForecasts.count

    }


    func updateCurrentWeatherUI() {
        cityNameLbl.text = segueData.cityName
        dateLbl.text = currentWeather.date
        currentTempLbl.text = "\(currentWeather.currentTemp)"
        currentWeatherType.text = currentWeather.weatherDesc
        currentWeatherImg.image = UIImage(named: "\(currentWeather.weatherType)L")
        dayHighTempLbl.text = "\(Int(currentWeather.highTemp))"
        dayLowTempLbl.text = "\(Int(currentWeather.lowTemp))"
    }



    @IBAction func backButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


}
```

I have a feeling that the problem has to do with how I am referencing it like the arrays of dictionarys that I handled already. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Update: result.value received. I am looking to parse the "currently" dictionary into my model then use the variables in the model class to populate my current forecast part of my UI. I can't paste in the entire result as it is larger in characters allowed for the post.

Second Update of result.value:

```
["latitude": 42.660851, "timezone": Europe/Madrid, "daily": {
data =     (
            {
        apparentTemperatureMax = "18.33";
        apparentTemperatureMaxTime = 1495022400;
        apparentTemperatureMin = "10.87";
        apparentTemperatureMinTime = 1495054800;
        cloudCover = "0.87";
        dewPoint = "11.73";
        humidity = "0.88";
        icon = rain;
        moonPhase = "0.7";
        ozone = "325.51";
        precipIntensity = "0.1753";
        precipIntensityMax = "0.3327";
        precipIntensityMaxTime = 1495040400;
        precipProbability = "0.54";
        precipType = rain;
        pressure = "1019.68";
```

Comment: Please do not use private backing variables to get constants.  This is a horrible 1:1 translation from Objective-C. Use standard properties with the `let` keyword.

Comment: My apologies. I am very new to swift and learned this through the courses I have taken but I have been noticing that it does not seem to be the normal convention through reading a lot of posts here. Any other advice for my original problem? Thanks.

Comment: Please add the beginning of the received data (the value of `result.value`)

Comment: I've updated the beginning of the received data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all lets declare a type alias for a JSON dictionary outside any class

```
typealias JSONDictionary = [String:Any]
```

The returned result (`result.value`) is an array rather than a dictionary (see the starting `[`).

In `downloadApiData` get the JSON data which is the first item in the array, replace

```
if let dict = result.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
```

with

```
if let array = result.value as? [JSONDictionary],
    let dict = array.first  {
```

Now pass `dict` to the initializer (not the value for `currently`)

```
let current = CurrentWeather(currentDict: dict)
```

The values for `currentTemp`, `weatherType` and `weatherDesc` are in the dictionary for key `currently`, the values for `highTemp` and `lowTemp` are in the first dictionary in array `data` in dictionary `daily`.

Your class `CurrentWeather` – *uncaged* from the private backing variables – is

```
class CurrentWeather {

    let currentTemp: Double
    let weatherType: String
    let highTemp: Double
    let lowTemp: Double
    let weatherDesc: String

    var date: String {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateStyle = .long
        dateFormatter.timeStyle = .none
        let currentDate = dateFormatter.string(from: Date())
        return "Today \(currentDate)"
    }


    init(currentDict: JSONDictionary) {
        if let currently = currentDict["currently"] as? JSONDictionary {
            self.currentTemp = currently["temperature"] as? Double ?? 0.0
            self.weatherType = currently["icon"] as? String ?? "n/a"
            self.weatherDesc = currently["summary"] as? String ?? "n/a"
        } else {
            self.currentTemp =  0.0
            self.weatherType = "n/a"
            self.weatherDesc = "n/a"

        }
        if let daily = currentDict["daily"] as? JSONDictionary,
            let data = daily["data"] as? [JSONDictionary],
            let firstDailyDict = data.first {

            self.highTemp = firstDailyDict["temperatureMax"] as? Double ?? 0.0
            self.lowTemp = firstDailyDict["temperatureMin"] as? Double ?? 0.0
        } else {
            self.highTemp = 0.0
            self.lowTemp = 0.0
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm still having an issue updating my UI with this. I changed self.currentTemp = currently["temperature"] as? Double ?? 0.0, as well as weatherType and weatherDesc but otherwise i've followed your advice exactly. Thanks for your help so far, i feel like we are almost there.

Comment: I am realizing that I made a mistake in the result.value that i pasted in. I had thought you wanted to see the structure of the 'currently' array so I edited to show that first.... obviously a mistake since the code you gave me was trying to access the first array in the dictionary. I've updated the beginning of the result.value. I believe that the currently array is the fourth object in the dictionary.

Comment: Now I'm confused. But with my code you should be able to find the solution by yourself. Read the JSON: `[]` is an array (zero-based index subscripted), `{}` is a dictionary (key subscripted). Values in double quotes are always strings, without double quotes they are `Int` (without decimal points) , `Double` (with decimal points) or `Bool` (`true` / `false`). `Null` is `NSNull`. It's pretty easy.

Comment: I was able to get it to work by removing 'let dict = array.first', adding my CurrentWeather class as a parameter to my 'updateCurrentWeatherUI' function, and passing 'current' into that function. Thanks for the input on my model class. I'm not sure if I have this correct but I was reading some documentation that stated swifts design is to have the model class private anyways so it is unnecessary to use private variables in ones models. If this is true, I will change my other models accordingly as it is a much cleaner code. Thanks again.

Comment: This is definitely true.